# Ruby on Rails Michael Hartl Errors: User pages signup page with valid information should create a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm following Michael Hartl's lessons on Ruby On Rails Chapter 7. I've finished reading Chapter 7 and followed step by step. However, I'm getting errors but I'm not sure what I've missed.

```
Failures:

  1) User pages signup page with valid information should create a user
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:24:in `user_params'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:36:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages signup page with invalid information should not create a user
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:24:in `user_params'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:23:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

    describe "profile page" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { visit user_path(user) }

      it { should have_content(user.name) }
      it { should have_title(user.name) }
    end

  describe "signup page" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end


end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        flash[:sucess] = "You've successfully created your account!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
        params.require.(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

views/users/new.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name %>

          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.text_field :email %>

          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password %>

          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

          <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "button [radius round]" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Result I get when I try to create an account using the signup page: 
*No messages are generated.
*Return to users#new page (all the info typed in before are deleted)
*No account created (Even if I enter information with correct format)

```
 --- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: 87UYaLE5HupPdMf/Q0SCmNnvOGd6SXdRvNTtOOAruJI=
user: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  name: ''
  email: ''
  password: ''
  password_confirmation: ''
commit: Create my account
controller: users
action: new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra dot before **(:user).permit** which should not be there in your user_params at the bottom of the users_controller.rb file.

Try this

```
private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for catching that. Also, you wouldn't possibly know why I can't create any account using signup page? Nothing happens when I create a new account.

Comment: I noticed your flash message only has one c in "success", just a heads up. What happens when you try to create a user? Do you get any errors? What is nothing happens?

Comment: Thank you for that too. I edited the file it didn't solve the problem I've having. When I try to create an account using the right information, not only the account is not created, but also I don't see any messages. It just returns to the user#new page when I click submit.

Comment: I'm not sure what was wrong and how I fixed it, but now I can create a user account. Thanks for your help!